# What kind of thrusters will the James Webb Space Telescope use for station keeping?

Tags: propulsion, fuel, attitude, station-keeping, james-webb-telescope

Question is fairly self-explanatory, but I couldn't find an answer on Google. I would expect ion thrusters because of their efficiency.

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to the [James Webb Space Telescope Initial Mid-Course Correction Monte Carlo Implementation using Task Parallelism](http://www.ai-solutions.com/Portals/0/AI%20Docs/Technical%20Paper%20Library%20pdf/2014/ISSFD24_Petersen_et_al_JWST_MCC_Monte_Carlo.pdf), J. Petersen et al. (PDF):

> #### 3.1 Propulsion System Overview
>
> Two sets of thrusters comprise the observatory’s propulsion system.
>   The first is a set of Secondary Combustion Augmented Thrusters (SCATs)
>   that are the main thrusters for the MCC maneuvers. The SCATs are
>   bi-propellant thrusters and draw from two separate tanks for a
>   hypergolic reaction. Two pairs of SCATs exist: one for MCC-1a and -1b,
>   and one for MCC-2. The MCC-2 SCAT is also employed in station keeping
>   throughout the life of the mission. Two pairs are required because the
>   center of mass of the observatory changes between MCC-1b and MCC-2
>   because of the sun shield deployment; the thrust vector from a SCAT is
>   directed through the center of mass at the time of that maneuver. Each
>   pair is composed of a primary and a redundant thruster (the respective
>   thrusters are coupled to the prime and redundant flight systems; only
>   one system is on at a time). SCAT 1 and 2 are the primary and
>   redundant pair for MCC-1a/b while SCAT 3 and 4 are the primary and
>   redundant pair for MCC-2 and stationkeeping. For a given maneuver only
>   one SCAT is on throughout that maneuver. The second set of thrusters
>   is composed of eight Dual Thruster Modules (DTMs), each comprising of
>   a primary and redundant Monopropellant Rocket Engine, 1 lbf, (MRE-1)
>   thruster. A schematic of the propulsion system appears in Fig. 3. The
>   MRE-1s consume hydrazine fuel only (and no oxidizer) from the same
>   tank as the SCATs. The MRE-1s are subdivided into two sets: MRE-1s 1
>   through 4, which are directed generally along the observatory J3 axis
>   for pitch and roll control, and MRE-1s 5 through 8, which are directed
>   radially about the J3 axis for yaw control `[3]`. A picture of the
>   spacecraft bus with the body J frame and orientation of the SCATs
>   relative to the J frame appears in Fig. 4. Together, the MRE-1s
>   on-pulse throughout a maneuver to control the attitude. Because of the
>   location and alignment of MRE-1s 1 through 4, any firings to control
>   pitch and roll during a maneuver may result in an additional ΔV to the
>   MCC maneuver. Therefore, thrust contributions from the MRE-1s must be
>   included in the design of the MCC maneuver.
>
> [image]
>
> <sup>**Figure
>   3. Schematic of the JWST propulsion system `[4]`.**</sup>
>   
>   [image]
>
> <sup>**Figure 4. An independent view of the spacecraft bus showing the
>   orientation of the body J frame along with the orientation of the
>   SCATs relative to the spacecraft bus. The +J1 axis points in the
>   general direction of the OTE boresight. The +J3 axis is roughly
>   perpendicular to the multilayer sunshield and pointing parallel to the
>   primary mirror (Image credit: jwst.nasa.gov)**</sup>
>
> ---
>
> #### References
>
> `[3]` Gidanian, D. 7.0. ACS design & analysis: Thruster Configuration
>   and Modeling. In James Webb Space Telescope (JWST) Spacecraft Attitude
>   Control Subsystem Hardware Critical Design Audit. Northrop Grumman, 28
>   August 2013.
>
> `[4]` Hammann, Jeff. JWST Propellant Budget Document, Northrup
>   Grumman. 19 July 2013. Document Number D40258

I wanted to share this as it describes JWST stationkeeping thrusters in detail, and as you can see in text and the attached images:

- SCAT (Secondary Combustion Augmented Thrusters) use [dinitrogen tetroxide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dinitrogen_tetroxide) (N<sub>2</sub>O<sub>4</sub>) as oxidizer and [hydrazine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrazine) (N<sub>2</sub>H<sub>4</sub>) as fuel components of its bipropellant, and
- DTMs (Dual Thruster Modules) each use two MREs (Monopropellant Rocket Engines) propelled only by hydrazine as low-thrust monopropellant and each providing 1 lbf (4.45 N) of thrust

Also see [James Webb Space Telescope Orbit Determination Analysis](http://ntrs.nasa.gov/search.jsp?R=20140008865), Yoon et al., NTRS 20140008865 (PDF) for explanation of JWST's three mid-course correction (MCC) maneuvers mentioned in the quote above.